# How to get the current cursor type, color and size in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse-cursor

Is there any way to get the current cursor type in Python Tkinter? For example "fleur"? Also, is there any method to get the current cursor color and the cursor size?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Means? The default cursor type?

Comment: @Sujay, no I was trying to get what the cursor type is, at the time of execution(I set it to another cursor at the beginning of the code). Thanks for the answer, that was what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Cool Cloud, kind of...I wanted to get the cursor type, not set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, yes:

Note: `insertbackground` sets the color of a cursor.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
entry1=Entry(root,cursor="fleur",insertbackground="red")
entry1.pack()
Button(root,text="Get cursor type and colour", command=lambda: print(entry1['cursor'],entry1['insertbackground'])).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, what you refer to as `cursor` is the cursor that the OP wants but the size and color of cursor that the OP wants is not of the insertion cursor of the entry widget but of the mouse cursor

Comment: @CoolCloud, the mouse pointer?

Comment: Yea that is what I think, not sure